# Upload GeoJSON files to ArcGIS Online content

Tags: geojson, arcgis-online, geopandas, arcgis-python-api

I would like to upload local GeoJSON files with Python automatically to ArcGIS Online. Now I have to upload them one for one, which takes quite some time. So I looked into the [ArcGIS API for Python](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/).

I saw two ways you can upload data to ArcGIS online:

1. With help of [the spatially enabled dataframe](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/introduction-to-the-spatially-enabled-dataframe/#:%7E:text=The%20Spatially%20Enabled%20), but this seems to be only working with shapefiles or an ESRI database and not GeoJSON files or a Geopandas dataframe
2. Using the add() method on a [ContentManager instance](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/accessing-and-creating-content/), with this method you can upload a pandas DataFrame or a csv file to ArcGIS Online. However, I cannot figure out how you can upload a polygon feature layer. All the examples are with points.

Can someone provide me with a simple example of how to upload GeoJSON (polygons) or GeoPandas DataFrame to ArcGIS Online with Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [Esri Community](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-python-questions/geojson-hosted-layer-error/td-p/847352) question contains the answer.

To summarize (since the final solution is spread out over multiple answers):

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

data_path = r'C:\path\example.geojson'
gis = GIS('https://arcgis.com', '<username>', '<password>')

item_properties = {'type': 'GeoJson', 'title': 'Test GeoJSON File', 'tags': 'test'}
item = gis.content.add(item_properties, data_path)
item.publish(file_type='geojson')
```